# Maximum number or results from a FQL query

Tags: facebook, size, facebook-fql

Is there a limit to the maximum number of results (considering selecting only a field from a table - ex: uid from users) one can get with a single FQL query?

Ex: select uid from users where condition has a 1M sized results set -> how many of those 1M would be returned to the caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) made by the Facebook on same issue the limit stands at 5000 results before the visibility check kicks in reducing even further the result set.